# ¿Como conectar 2 bases de datos con laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

Estoy intentando realizar conexión a 2 bases de datos, ambas se encuentran en el mismo servidor pero en diferentes dominios la primer base de datos es la local donde tengo mi sistema y es la que carga por defecto pero deseo conectar la otra base de datos la cual esta en otro dominio

Alguien tiene alguna idea de ¿como realizar dicho proceso?
soy algo nuevo en esto
Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Estableciendo conexiones

Lo primero que debemos hacer es definir las credenciales correspondientes a cada conexión de base de datos que deseamos utilizar, para ello accedemos al archivo de configuración de nuestra aplicación config\database.php:

```
'connections'  => [

    'mysql'  => [
    'driver'     => 'mysql',
    'host'       => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'   => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'   => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'   => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'    => 'utf8',
    'collation'  => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'     => '',
    'strict'     => false,
    ],

   ‘comments’  => [
   'driver'     => 'mysql',
   'host'       => env('COMMENTS_HOST', 'localhost'),
   'database'   => env('COMMENTS_DATABASE', 'forge'),
   'username'   => env('COMMENTS_USERNAME', 'forge'),
   'password'   => env('COMMETNS_PASSWORD', ''),
   'charset'    => 'utf8',
   'collation'  => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'     => '',
   'strict'     => false,
    ],

],
```

En este caso estamos creando dos conexiones, una llamada mysql y otra llamada comments.

Cuando no se especifique la conexión a utilizar el sistema tomará el valor por defecto, en este caso ‘mysql’.

Recuerden que si trabajamos haciendo uso de las buenas prácticas, los valores de las variables estarán definidas dentro del archivo .env de nuestra aplicación.

.env :

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=base_de_datos_principal
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
COMMENTS_HOST=localhost
COMMENTS_DATABASE=base_de_datos_comments
COMMENTS_USERNAME=homestead
COMMENTS_PASSWORD=secret
```

**Definiendo modelos con diferentes bases de datos**

app/User.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {

     /**
     * The database connection used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $connection = 'comments';

     /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $table = 'forms';

     //Etc...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usando conexiones de bases de datos múltiples**

Cuando estamos usando conexiones múltiples, puedes acceder a cada conexión por medio del método **`connection`** en el Facade **`DB`**. El nombre **`name`** pasado al método de conexión **`connection`** debería corresponder a una de las conexiones listadas en tu archivo de configuración **`config/database.php:`**

```
$users = DB::connection('foo')->select(...);
```

También puedes acceder a los datos nativos de la instancia **`PDO`** subyacente que usa el método **`getPdo`** en una instancia de conexión:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
```

[mas informacion](https://documentacion-laravel.com/database.html#introduccion)